# Scroll to a specific part of a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane, jtextcomponent

Using [`Cobra`](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp), I have a void function which will scroll to a given node of a dom tree or a given pixel of the `htmlpane`. When I use `JFrame.setContentPane()` function to set the `htmlpane` as the container, and I use the `scroll()` function to scroll the specefic point, it's not working.

Here is the code:

```
HtmlRendererContext rendererContext = (HtmlRendererContext) new  LocalHtmlRendererContext(htmlPanel, uAgent);
DocumentBuilderImpl builder = new DocumentBuilderImpl(uAgent, rendererContext);
Document document = builder.parse(url);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
htmlPanel.scroll(500, 300);
//frame.getContentPane().add(htmlPanel);
frame.setContentPane(htmlPanel);
```

and if you see the following code:

```
frame.setContentPane(htmlPanel.scroll(500, 300));
```

it says:

> no void function allowed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the Cobra API you are using but in most cases GUI components have to lay themselves out before you can scroll. This is because before you add a component to a container it does not know what size it will be. Try delaying the scroll and see if it helps:

```
frame.setContentPane(htmlPanel);
frame.setVisible(true);
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        htmlPanel.scroll(500, 300);
    }
});
```

Comment: where should i put it? before frame.setsize(); or after it?

Comment: i copy pasted your code and rerun the program but nothing changed

Comment: Try after frame.setVisible(true).

Comment: it worked out where ever i put the code, the only fault i did , was to include set.visible(); part of your code in my program then it repeated twicw and then no action, but now it's working, thank you anyway ;)

Comment: now the above problem is been solved but there is a new problem arises that you can read about it here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377859/scrolling-to-the-other-part-of-the-webpage) just in case if you dont mind :d